# Pandas: Combining Actual and Prediction Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, prediction

I’m trying to combine the actual target values and predicted target value as a dataframe. However, I’m getting the following error. Not sure why this is happening.

```
a = pd.DataFrame(y_test, columns=['Actual'])
b = pd.DataFrame(final_model.predict(X_test), columns=['Predictions'])
c = pd.concat([a, b])
c.head()
```

[Actual Vs Prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/litAf.png)

Comment: Are you receiving an actual error message? If you are, please post the error trace. If you are not receiving an error trace, please tell us what your expected outcome is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@nimbous already answered but if you want less intermediate steps, use a dictionary to create a df.

`c = pd.DataFrame({"Actual": y_test, "Predictions": final_model.predict(X_test)})`

Answer (score 1):

You can assign to a new column directly. So long as the shape of y_test and the predictions from the model are the same, you should have no issue doing the following:

```
base = pd.DataFrame()
base["actual"] = y_test
base["predictions"] = final_model.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)`, although this is not a neat solution.